# Stop two divs from having the same height after clearfix

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I met a problem and I describe it in short code.

http://jsfiddle.net/hughgr/wx2w70dx/1/

```css
.div1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: #F00;
}
.div2 {
  margin-left: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
.div3 {
  background: #0F0;
}
.clearfix {} .clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  content: '1';
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  clear: both;
}
body,
html,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3 clearfix">
      <div class="float">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use "clearfix" on `div3` which makes `div3` has the same height with `div1`.

And I just want `div3` adjust its height with its child 'float' div.

Can someone explain why this happen and how to fix it.

ps:I still have to use float to layout the whole thing.

===============================================

set div3 overflow:hidden can solve this problem,but still not perfect,what if some element in the div3 was set to position:absolute and need to show outside div3...

Comment: can you draw your expected result ?

Comment: expect:the green block should not reveal,it should have the same height with blue block

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wx2w70dx/2/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Tushar smart solution. but it's not so elegant to use display:table. can you explain why clearfix makes green block reveal

Comment: Do you expect [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8pprhttp/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7zp69txg/